# Calculating the entropy of an attribute in the ID3 algorithm when a split is perfectly classified

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have been reading about the ID3 algorithm recently and it says that the best attribute to be selected for splitting should result in the maximum information gain which can be computed with the help of the entropy.

I have written a simple python program to compute the entropy. It is shown below:

```
def _E(p, n):
    x = (p/(p+n))
    y = (n/(p+n))
    return(-1* (x*math.log2(x)) -1* (y*math.log2(y)))
```

However suppose we have a table consisting of 10 elements as follows:

x = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

y = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Where x is the attribute and y is the class. Here P(0) = 0.8 and P(1) = 0.2. The entropy will be as follows:

Entropy(x) = 0.8*_E(5, 3) + 0.2*_E(2, 0)

However the second split P(1) is perfectly classified and this results in a math error since log2(0) is negative infinity. How is the entropy calculated in such cases?

Comment: You should ask this question over at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

**Entropy is a measure of impurity.** So if a node is pure it means entropy is zero.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/HashCode55/ML_from_scratch/blob/master/decision_tree.py) -

```
def information_gain(data, column, cut_point):
    """
    For calculating the goodness of a split. The difference of the entropy of parent and 
    the weighted entropy of children.
    :params:attribute_index, labels of the node t as `labels` and cut point as `cut_point`
    :returns: The net entropy of partition 
    """
    subset1, subset2 = divide_data(data, column, cut_point) 
    lensub1, lensub2 = len(subset1), len(subset2)  
    #if the node is pure return 0 entropy
    if len(subset1) == 0 or len(subset2) == 0:
        return (0, subset1, subset2)     
    weighted_ent = (len(subset1)*entropy(subset1) + len(subset2)*entropy(subset2)) / len(data)  
    return ((entropy(data) - weighted_ent), subset1, subset2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The entropy of a split measures the uncertainty associated with the class labels in that split. In a binary classification problem (classes = {0,1}), the probability of class 1 (in your text, x) can range from 0 to 1. The entropy is maximum (with a value of 1) when x=0.5. Here both classes are equally probable. The entropy is minimum when one of the classes is absent, i.e. either x=0 or x=1. Here, there is no uncertainty regarding the class, hence the entropy is 0.

Graph of entropy (y-axis) vs x (x-axis):

[image: Graph of entropy (y-axis) vs x (x-axis)]

The following calculation shows how to deal with the entropy calculation mathematically, when x=0 (the case when x=1 is analogous):

[image]

In your program, you could treat x=0 and x=1 as special cases, and return 0. For other values of x, the above equation can be used directly.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed to be confident that B should, in fact, return 0 when x = {0, 1}.